# Silverlight Datagrid Refresh current page

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, ria

I have datagrid which is bound to a list of objects from entity framework and is paged using a datapager. My question is- how do I refresh only the current "page" that it is on? For example, if I am on page 17 of 100 and click refresh, I want the query to go out and refresh the data for page 17 only.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should keep you page number in a variable and use it after the refresh in the dataPager pageIndex property